# Regular Expression Telephone Number Validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate Phone Numbers that follow the next Pattern

```
01\d{9} 
2\d{7}
```

But The user can enter more than one number separated by space or in one input field
So I come up with the regular expression

```
/(?:(?:01\d{9}$)|(?:2\d{7}$) ){1,}
A Test Sample
"01226113130 26322612 24586154 01004598654"
```

My Expression Doesn't match this sample, any help ?

**Solution**
For others if they fail in the problem, You can try Jerry Solution or this one

```
(?:(?:(?:01\d{9}(?:[\- \,])*)|(?:2\d{7}[\- \,]*))){1,}
```

Comment: my bad, I will correct it immediately

Comment: Provide test cases.. what you expect to pass and fail.

Comment: @Layke I provided one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
^(?:(?:01\d{9}|2\d{7}) ){1,}(?:01\d{9}|2\d{7})$
```

Your current regex has `(?:01\d{9}$)|(?:2\d{7}$)` where the `$` forced it to 'prematurely end' the match, so removing this was the first thing to do. Then `(?:01\d{9})|(?:2\d{7})` can be re-written as `(?:01\d{9}|2\d{7})`. I added a `^` for the beginning of the string.

Afterwards, this regex will only validate strings ending with a space, so add another `(?:01\d{9}|2\d{7})` at the end and finally conclude with `$`.

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/kX2uS0).

Oh, also, it might be better to turn the `{1,}` into `*` like this:

```
^(?:(?:01\d{9}|2\d{7}) )*(?:01\d{9}|2\d{7})$
```

Comment: Yes It worked and I also Edited Mine and It Worked
BTW  I found the great tool
[link](http://www.debuggex.com/)

Comment: @ShadyAtef I'm glad! And yup, debuggex is nice with pictures, though I prefer regex101 by far for the advanced regex features available, such as `\G`, `\K` or lookbehinds!

Comment: If his goal is 1+ matches, that star should be a ```+```. Rather than repeating the expression.

Comment: I have shortened your expression to this one

    ^(?:(?:01\d{9}|2\d{7}) *)+$

Comment: @DivinusVox But in the second expression, I added a compulsory match of numbers, so it must match at least once. Using `+` would fail to match a single number.